# Compiling F# source on Windows with Mono

Tags: windows, f#, mono

I have downloaded `mono-6.0.0.334-x64-0.msi` from Mono-project website: https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/

However, I am not clear what command do I use to compile F# source files (say mysrc.fs). There is no `fsharpc` or `fsharpi` command installed with mono. I have tried to search the internet but a commonly quoted page does not mention mono as an option: https://fsharp.org/use/windows/

Can I or can I not compile F# source files on Windows with mono? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to use mono on Windows, do you have some specialized use case?

Answer (score 1):

The official [document](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/languages/) states that

*F# is a hybrid language that brings flavors of functional languages and imperative languages, developed by Microsoft. They release compiler that targets mono in **[some releases](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/04/12/f-2-0-released-as-part-of-visual-studio-2010.aspx)**.*

It seems like to target mono you need to download [FSharp.Compiler.Tools](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Compiler.Tools) nuget package assembled form the official [F# compiler repo](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp).

Then for mono-specific compiler options you can refer to the [special doc in language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/compiler-options).